# Quartz .net 6 : Execute method does not work

Tags: c#, .net, task, quartz.net, class-library

Exetuce method in Ijob is not triggered.

class library code:

```
   public static async void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dbContext = new SqlDbContext())
                {
                    ISchedulerFactory schedContext = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                    var scheduler = schedContext.GetScheduler();

                    if (!scheduler.Result.IsStarted)
                    {
                         await scheduler.Result.Start();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("job1 trigger job bağlama");


                    //IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().WithIdentity(jobItem.JOB_KEY, "group1").Build();
                            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobExecuteService>().WithIdentity("JobExecuteService", "MailGrup").Build();



                            //ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            //    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                            //        .DailyAtHourAndMinute(jobItem.JOB_TIME.Hours, jobItem.JOB_TIME.Minutes)
                            //        .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Turkey Standard Time"))
                            //    )
                            //    .WithDescription(jobItem.DESCRIPTION)
                            //    .Build();

                            //ISimpleTrigger TriggerGorev = (ISimpleTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("JobExecuteService").StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow).WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever()).Build();



                            //                        var example = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            //.WithIdentity("JobExecuteService", "MailGrup")
                            //.ForJob("JobExecuteService", "MailGrup")
                            //.WithSimpleSchedule(o =>
                            //{
                            //    o.WithRepeatCount(5)
                            //        .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                            //})
                            //.Build();


                            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(10,25))
    .ForJob(job)
    .Build();

                           await  scheduler.Result.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }




public class JobExecuteService: IJob
    {
        private readonly IPublisherService _publisherService;
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public JobExecuteService(IPublisherService PublisherService, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _publisherService = PublisherService;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
              
                Task taskA = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello from task at {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                taskA.Start();
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("HelloJob is executing.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }
            //return Task.FromResult(result);
            
        }
}
```

I tried every way. I tried a thousand things. but it didn't. The ones in the comment line are the methods I've always tried.Quartz methods are defined in the library. Quartz lifting part is defined in the program.cs file of the mvc project.The above codes are defined in the library project.
The codes below are in the mvc project. are linked to each other by reference.

mvc code program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    // Joblarımı oluşturduğum servisi başlatıyorum
    JobSchedulerService.Start();
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
});
// ASP.NET Core hosting
builder.Services.AddQuartzServer(options =>
{
    // when shutting down we want jobs to complete gracefully
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

**update:** I opened a project from scratch and tried it with the same codes in a single project. it happened. So the problem is because I make configurations in different projects. I want to use my quartz codes in class library project. but my main project is mvc project. How should I configure it?

**Update 2:** It doesn't work because I created a constructor in the JobExecuteService class. It works when I don't create the constructor. but I need to create constructor. how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i solved this using configurationBuilder directly on Execute Method:

```
IConfiguration _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
   .Build();

IDsService _services = new DsService(_configuration);
```